# How to persist an object with a reference to itself using Doctrine?

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following schema where `TestEntity#testEntity` has a reference itself and cannot be `NULL`.

```
#[ORM\Entity)]
class TestEntity
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $name;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: TestEntity::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private $testEntity;
    
    // Standard setters and getters
}
```

My script to create and persist an object is as follows:

```
$testEntity = new \App\Entity\TestEntity();
$testEntity
->setName('hello')
->setTestEntity($testEntity)
;
$output->writeln(sprintf('BEFORE persist: Parent: name: %s id: %d Child: name: %s id: %d', $testEntity->getName(), $testEntity->getId(), $testEntity->getTestEntity()->getName(), $testEntity->getTestEntity()->getId()));
$this->entityManager->persist($testEntity);
$output->writeln(sprintf('AFTER persist:  Parent: name: %s id: %d Child: name: %s id: %d', $testEntity->getName(), $testEntity->getId(), $testEntity->getTestEntity()->getName(), $testEntity->getTestEntity()->getId()));
try{
    $this->entityManager->flush();
}
catch(Exception $exception) {
    $output->writeln($exception->getMessage());
    return Command::FAILURE;
}
```

I execute the script and get the following error:

```
BEFORE persist: Parent: name: hello id: 0 Child: name: hello id: 0
AFTER persist:  Parent: name: hello id: 7 Child: name: hello id: 7
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7
ERROR:  null value in column "test_entity_id" of relation "test_entity" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (7, null, hello).
```

Why does it fail?  If I wasn't using Doctrine and used native SQL queries with PostgreSQL, I recognized I would need to use deferred constraints.  I don't know whether or not Doctrine uses deferred constraints, but regardless as seen by the output Doctrine is smart enough to set the PK after the entity is persisted.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Doesn't seem like this schema mapping would be possible using the entity manager due to the flush operation still inserting `null` initially and then executing an `UPDATE` afterwards to associate the inserted ID.  Even if the ID is manually specified... Seems the only option for using the entity manager would be to allow nullable with validation on the entity.

Comment: @WillB.  Thanks Will,  Ended up concluding the same.  If the ID is manually specified, then I would get a FK constraint fault unless deferred constraints were used which evidently isn't supported by Doctrine since all DB's don't support.  Hope Doctrine isn't wasting an query to get the PK during the persist operation but not sure how else it gets set.  Feel free to add an answer as such and I would be happy to select it.

Comment: According to the documentations, the generated PK is available during [postPersist](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/events.html). *"Generated primary key values are available in the postPersist event."*    You can manually execute the statement `$em->getConnection()->executeStatement('SET CONSTRAINTS  fk_test_entity_id DEFEERED')` but did not work for me even while in a transaction or manually setting the column to `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` Due to the `INSERT null`, `UPDATE test_entity_id = id`.

Comment: Line of code referencing the [post-insert](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.10.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L983) operation for new entity associations in the persistNew logic. Seems the PK referenced is assigned using `SELECT NEXTVAL('test_entity_id_seq')`

Comment: @WillB.  Nice detective work!  Also looks like a sub-optimized query by Doctrine.  Not that I am complaining as overly-optimized is in my opinion worse than sub-optimized, but still is good to be aware of.

Comment: Regarding your attempt to change to deferred, understand that it didn't work for you and very much appreciate you taking the time, but just checking if your `DEFEERED` was a typo in this post or in your actual code.

Comment: It was a typo in my comment only, My FK's are encoded also. Additionally failed when I applied the rule directly to the column, expecting it to working within a transaction.

Comment: @WillB. No more questions but just wanted to share something of interest.  `#[ORM\GeneratedValue]` results in the ID being defined post persist but  `#[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'IDENTITY')]` does not and will only be set after the flush.  Can't find documentation describing this and just found by trial and error.

Comment: Related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/6429) with several other references about the confusing behavior and [Docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies): `ORM\GeneratedValue` defaults to `AUTO`, which for PostgreSQL is `SEQUENCE` prompting the `NEXTVAL()` query where `IDENTITY` for PostgreSQL is supposed to use the `SERIAL` column type. *"special identity columns in the database that generate a value on insertion of a row"* guessing *insertion of a row* implies not on persist.